# Getting date format patterrn by country

Tags: java

I'm trying to print date format pattern depending on Country.
Like here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country

My try:

```
public class DateFormatTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] locales = Locale.getISOCountries();

        for (String countryCode : locales) {

            Locale locale = new Locale("", countryCode);

            DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, locale);

            SimpleDateFormat simple = (SimpleDateFormat) dateFormat;

            String pattern = simple.toPattern().replaceAll("\\byy\\b", "yyyy");

            System.out.println(
                    "{" +
                    "id : '" + locale.getCountry() + "', " +
                    "format : '" + pattern + "'" +
                    "},");

        }

    }

}
```

But I got: `'M/d/yyyy'` for all countries.

For Germany, for example I'm expecting something like this: `dd.MMM.yyyy` for UK: `MMM/dd/yyyy`

Q: How to get date format pattern by country?

Answer (score 1):

Ah...

I should specify language:

```
 Locale locale = new Locale("en", countryCode);
```

Which is a weird behavior...

Ah.. and where it dots or slashes it depends on language too.

If I use "de", then I have dots.. Hm..